# Javascript manipulation of video tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, html, video

I am trying to play a video on an iPhone which is encoded as an MP4 but has the wrong extension and mime type (which can't be changed on the server).

If I use something like:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="internal.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <Your browser does not support the video tag>
<video>
```

can I use Javascript / jQuery to make the video player think its play a file called internal.mp4 but is actually playing something like

```
http://192.168.0.1/video.tjc
```

Answer (score 1):

The source-tag's attribute `type` is made to define a MIME-type, meas your browser knows what to expect, but that isn't really the problem.
MP4 is a MIME-type but that doesn't tell your browser which codec the video is compressed with. The file should do that but in your case it seems to be mixed up.

Anyways there is a Codec attribute in HTML5 as defined here:
http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4281.txt

You should really read this, as it is the best intro into Web Video:
http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html

Here you find a complete list of all codec type parameters:
http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Video_type_parameters

Comment: That looks good and thanks for the info, but i though that the mime type was served by the web server and the mime type in the video src was overwriten so didnt have any effect

Comment: @user2302694 effect on what? The video couldn't be played. Well that makes sense if you don't know how (speaking as a browser).
You can digg a little bit deeper in here: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#mime-types

Comment: Hi John have had a look at the documents and they imply that like you say i should be able to force the mime type, i am a bit stuck i have worked out the video mime type is "aac-lc-sbr-ps" but can't work out how to convert into this kind of format "avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2" - any ideas cheers

Comment: @user2302694 I think you are going the wrong way. AAC isn't even supported by all browsers and was dropped in Chrome. You should really get your video source cleaned up. You could transcode the video stream using VLC as described here: http://www.videolan.org/doc/videolan-howto/en/ch09.html

Comment: Read this: http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html
Its simply the best intro into web video there is.

Comment: Hi i have no control over the codec etc as its being served up by an embedded server , for my app (iPhone) to work i need to find a way of working with the file as it is cheers Toby

Comment: Ok, lets give it a try then. Whats your Video and whats our Audio Profile. MPEG4 is modular so you need to know both.
Here is a list of all video type parameters and its availability in different browsers: http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Video_type_parameters

If you need help just post the source URL.

BTW you should keep in mind that you can't use just any stream on the internet without running into copyright issues in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
$('#divVideo video source').attr('src', videoFile);
```

Then:

```
$("#divVideo video")[0].load();
```

Hope this helps!